# GitLab CI with code quality showing unwanted findings

Tags: java, gitlab-ci

I have a selfhosted GitLab instance running with various Java projects on it. The projects are built with Gradle. In order to cache dependencies, I've configured Gradle to store its stuff inside the project directory and added GitLab caching for the `.gradle/caches` folder.

It looks like this:

```yaml
variables:
  GRADLE_CACHE: "my-project-cache"
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle"

cache:
  key: $GRADLE_CACHE
  paths:
    - .gradle/caches/
```

This works so far. The `.gradle` folder is not under version control, it's just created when GitLab executes the build job.

Next I wanted to add GitLab code quality to the project. I don't have experience with it, as I've been using SonarQube so far, so this is my first try.

I've read that the setup should be quite simple, basically it is adding:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
```

This will add a `code_quality` job and execute it within the test stage. And I can see results in the merge request widget of GitLab. However, what I see there is not what I expect. It shows multiple findings like this one:

```
Minor - TODO found
in .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache/apache/16/8a90e31780e5cd0685ccaf25836c66e3b4e163b7/apache-16.pom:238
```

So it looks like GitLab scans the `.gradle` folder, which it should not.

My Java project has its sources in default folders `src/main/java` and code for unit tests in `src/test/java`. I thought it might be good to set the source directory for the `code_quality` job to `src/main/java`, so that it scans just contents of this directory.

GitLab docs says that a variable `SOURCE_CODE` can be set: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#available-cicd-variables

I tried this, but it doesn't have any effect:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml

code_quality:
  variables:
    SOURCE_CODE: "src/main/java"
```

I took a look at GitLab's `Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml` file (see [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml)) and saw they set `SOURCE_CODE` in the script block of their job:

```
  script:
    - export SOURCE_CODE=$PWD
```

I'm not sure, but maybe this overwrites the `SOURCE_CODE` variable, which I've set in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

So I wonder what a correct setup would look like. Can you give me hints please?

**Workaround:** I didn't find out how or if the `SOURCE_CODE` variable can be set correctly. I found a solution for my problem though: I moved Gradle home away from the project directory into `/cache/.gradle` and removed the GitLab cache. `/cache` is a volume, which gets mounted by default, so putting `.gradle` into it works well for me.